# How to Navigate using list in react native elements

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have integrated react native elements list items for side Drawer in my project but here I am not able to navigate using list items to another page

Here I have updated the full page code without the styles

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9m9M.jpg)

I have already tried the following below code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
 import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
 import CartScreen from '../screens/CartScreen';
 import {
      View,
      Image,
      ScrollView,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Keyboard,
   } from 'react-native';
  import { DrawerActions, StackNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';
  import { List, ListItem, Button, navigationOptions } from 'react- 
  native-elements';
  import { Ionicons, AntDesign, EvilIcons, Feather, FontAwesome } from 
    '@expo/vector-icons';


const list = [
    {
         title: 'HOME',
         icon: 'shopping-cart',
         page: 'MyCart',
        color: '#D3D3D3'     
   },
{
    title: 'OFFERS',
    icon: 'notifications',
    page: 'CartScreen'
}, ]

 const sideMenuComponent = props =>
  (
       <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>     
    <View style={styles.container2}>
                {
                    list.map((item, i) => (
                        <ListItem
                            key={i}
                            title={item.title}
                            leftIcon={{ name: item.icon }}
                            linearGradientProps={{
                                colors: ['#D3D3D3', '#D3D3D3'],
                                start: [1, 0],
                                end: [0.2, 0],
                              }}
                            onPress={() => 
                      this.props.navigation.navigate(item.page)}
                            borderTopWidth={1}
                            titleStyle={{ color: Colors.textColor }}

                        />
                    ))
                }
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
     );
class SideMenu extends Component {

        goToOtherScreen(page) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate(page);
          }

    render() {
         return sideMenuComponent(this.props);
       }
  }
```

export default SideMenu;

Comment: What is your error ? Are you using `react-navigation` ?

Comment: No, not in this page and I get undefined is not an object error

Comment: According to the error that you got, your current screen doesn't have access to the navigation object in his props. Hard to say why without seeing the rest of your code

Comment: I have updated the full page code

Answer (score 0):

You could Wrap the list item with touchable opacity and the onPress() function of the touchable opacity should navigate where you want to.

Comment: I've never used React Native Elements list before, but what I do when I use FlatList (which i recomend), is wraping the Item of the list with a touchable opacity. This way, you can click the hole item of the list, and the onPress method of the tochable would be navigate